# Python3 weakref WeakMethod and thread safety

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to create a simple callback that can be registered to an object from another thread. The initial object that calls the callback is running on its own thread in this case.

This is best illustrated through the following example:

```python
from pprint import pprint
import sys
import weakref
import threading
import time

class DummyController(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.name = "fortytwo"

  def callback(self):
    print("I am number : " + self.name)

class SomeThread(threading.Thread):

  def __init__(self, listener):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.listener = listener

  def run(self):
    time.sleep(1)
    dummy = DummyController()
    self.listener.register_callback(dummy.callback)
    time.sleep(5)
    del dummy



class Listener(threading.Thread):

  def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.runner = weakref.WeakMethod(self.default_callback)
    self.counter = 20

  def default_callback(self):
    print("Not implemented")

  def register_callback(self, function):
    self.runner = weakref.WeakMethod(function)

  def run(self):
    while self.counter:
      try:
        self.runner()()
      except Exception as e:
        pprint(e)

      self.counter -= 1
      time.sleep(1)



listen = Listener()
some = SomeThread(listen)

listen.start()
some.start()
```

Now the above code works just fine. But I am concerned about thread-safety here. Reading through [weakref docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html), it isn't very clear if weakref is really thread safe or not, except for the line:

> Changed in version 3.2: Added support for thread.lock, threading.Lock, and code objects.

I might be simply not reading that right. Do I need to add locking, or is everything actually fine and pretty thread safe?

Many thanks

Comment: The doc means in version 3.2 you can make a weak reference to thread.lock, threading.Lock and code objects but doesn't mean there is an internal lock. And I don't understand which part could be unsafe? Could you give an example to explain?

Comment: My worries come from the fact that the `Listener` runs the callback of the object function, but another thread (`SomeThread`) then deletes the object. Since it's using the `weakref.WeakMethod` the object should be immediatelly removed from memory without the involvement of a garbage collector so I am wondering if when deleting the callback function object would cause a racing condition if both the object is being deleted and the function being called at the same time.
Is that a little clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I understand. This is not a problem about thread safe, but just a problem about `weak reference`.

There is an executable example:

```
from pprint import pprint
import sys
import weakref
import threading
import time
import gc

class SomeThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, listener):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.listener = listener

    def run(self):
        class test:    # simplify this example.
            def callback(self, count):
                print(count)
        time.sleep(1)
        dummy = test()
        self.listener.register_callback(dummy.callback)
        time.sleep(5)
        del dummy
        gc.collect()  # add this line to do garbage collecting.


class Listener(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.runner = weakref.WeakMethod(self.default_callback)
        self.counter = 20

    def default_callback(self):
        print("Not implemented")

    def register_callback(self, function):
        self.runner = weakref.WeakMethod(function)

    def run(self):
        while self.counter:
            try:
                self.runner()(self.counter)
            except Exception as e:
                pprint(e)

            self.counter -= 1
            time.sleep(1)


listen = Listener()
some = SomeThread(listen)

listen.start()
some.start()
```

output:

```
TypeError('default_callback() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given',)
TypeError('default_callback() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given',)
18
17
16
15
TypeError("'NoneType' object is not callable",)
TypeError("'NoneType' object is not callable",)
TypeError("'NoneType' object is not callable",)
```

If you explicitly call `gc.collect()`, `callback` loses its last strong reference and then it becomes `None`. As you will never know when will `gc` collect garbage, there is a potential issue.

It is no matter you use thread or not, just a normal behave of `weak reference`.

BTW, be careful that exiting `SomeThread.run` will also implicitly `del dummy`, you can test it by removing `del dummy` and moving `gc.collect()` into `try` block.

Comment: Yeah, it is one of the reasons why I am using the wakref, since I "need" the callback lose its last strong reference. Hence the exception capturing, however I was worrying about the fact that such a thing where the strong reference is destroyed in another thread would create a race condition. 
Many thanks for the answer